# GroupLayout - simple component positioning

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I have been using `GridBagLayout` but turned to `GroupLayout` recently. Below is a screen shot of what I have and what I need. Then the code.

What do I need to change?

### What I have

[image]

### What I need

[image]

I think i am supposed to be using the `TRAILING` and `LEADING` constants but the GUI is not responding. Could this be the reason most SO advise to people is to avoid `GroupLayout`? I have been using `GridBagLayout` before, which is more complex, and `GroupLayout` code seems much simpler. That's why am using it. Code that I have is given below, what do I need, to have the desired effect?

```
public class GroupLayoutOne extends JFrame{

   JLabel lbText = new JLabel("Text one");
   JTextField txText = new JTextField();
   JLabel lbText2 = new JLabel("Text two");
   JTextField txText2 = new JTextField();
   JPanel pnCompo = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        GroupLayoutOne glx = new GroupLayoutOne();
        glx.init();
        glx.setVisible(true);
        glx.setSize(new Dimension(400,200));
        glx.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

    void init(){
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(gl);
    
        pnCompo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        pnCompo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("More Components"));
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(lbText)
                        .addComponent(lbText2)
                        .addComponent(pnCompo)
                 )
                 .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(txText)
                        .addComponent(txText2)
    
                )
        );
        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                 .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(lbText)
                        .addComponent(txText)
                   
                 )
                 .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(lbText2)
                        .addComponent(txText2)
                   
                )
                .addComponent(pnCompo)
        );
        pack();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at http://www.miglayout.com/

Comment: Yeah, i have been avoiding it deliberately, seems it time a took a deep dive into it.Thanks.

Comment: *"I have been using `GridBagLayout` before, which is more complex, and `GroupLayout` code seems much simpler."* Wow! If I had a dollar for every time I've heard that, including just now, I'd have .. ***one* dollar**. The 2nd 'what I need' GUI appears fairly easy to make with `GridBagLayout` - I'd use it. `GroupLayout` is more commonly used in by GUI builders. I've only ever encountered one (again) person that seemed to be able to write group layout code by hand!

Comment: only one dollar! well, grouplayout as I said **seems** simpler, may be the truth is out there.GridBagLayout is very powerful, and **very taxing** (e.g lots of typing,less thinking) to get right, GroupLayout to me seems to take a more abstract or conceptual approach,which means less typing but more thinking(this is how i prefer my programming experience to be).Am looking to unload the GridBagLayout burden,seems allover SO most people advice not to handcode usingGroupLayout. Btw, _I hand code all my GUI's_, and GridBagLayout sometimes may give me a headache to get perfectly.

Comment: Tip: Add @keuleJ (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"GridBagLayout sometimes may give me a headache to get perfectly."* As compared to .. what the `GroupLayout` is currently doing? Good luck with it if you intend to keep using GL. Get back to me if you decide GBL is worth a (giving another) shot.

Comment: @Afroid1000 If you want to code your GUIs by hand and want to do it with less typing I would definitively look at MiGLayout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your init method with the below code:
BTW: Use NetBeans or Eclipse to draw swing UI. It would be much easier than writing code yourself.

```
    GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(gl);

    pnCompo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    pnCompo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("More Components"));
    gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                    .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(lbText)
                    .addComponent(txText))

             .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                     .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(lbText2)
                    .addComponent(txText2))

             .addComponent(pnCompo))
             )
    );
    gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
             .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(lbText)
                    .addComponent(txText))
             .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup().addComponent(lbText2)
                    .addComponent(txText2)
            )
            .addComponent(pnCompo)
    );
    pack();
```

Comment: ok! so this is the shortest code to do such a simple positioning!!?.Suddenly its too verbose,_"BTW: Use NetBeans or Eclipse to draw swing UI"_.Please clarify, Do u mean that Its advisable to run swing apps on IDE'S as opposed to running them without an IDE (as in running them directly from cmd if one is on windows)? Thanks.

Comment: Running doesn't matter. What I mean is designing UI on editor. You can drag and drop UI component.  Check this out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFr06ZKIpSM

Comment: Am so past drag & dropping. My quest for extra functionality and super-awesome GUI's lead me to start hand coding. It was painful at first, but worth it thanks to **MadProgrammer** and **camickr** others whose answers are great tutorials. For now,i just wanted an alternative to GridBagLayout, i think MigLayout as suggested by @keuleJ is it.

Comment: I see. So if you are familiar with the drag-drop concept and still want to write code so that you can learn extra.. you have way to go :)